# Using variables in Serverless resource name

Tags: serverless-framework

In my serverless.yml I have:

```
  public-function:
    handler: function.Handler
```

I want to parametrise the public-function line but I'm not sure how to do this. I know I can add a name: attribute to the function and use the ${} syntax documented at https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/ but this only half solves my problem as public-function is used by Serverless as a basis for the names of other resources which I also want to have parametrised names.

Is there some way of using variables in the resource name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declared function key (i.e. `public-function`) is only a [reference in the stack](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources#aws-cloudformation-resource-reference). There is no reason to change it at build time as the name is arbitrary.

If you want to customise the details of the deployed function, [change its configuration](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/).

For example, change the name of the function to something else using environment variables:

```
functions:
    main:
        handler: function.Handler
        name: ${self:provider.stage}-${env:FUNCTION_NAME}
```

If you are exporting the resource to another stack, you can define the export name like so:

```
resources:
    Outputs:
        MainFunction:
            Value:
                Fn::GetAtt: [MainLambdaFunction, Arn]
            Export:
                Name: ${self:provider.stage}-${env:CUSTOM_EXPORT_NAME}
```

The stage scoping to both of these examples is recommended but not required; you can name your functions, resources, and outputs anything you want.

Comment: Thanks - I thought the declared function key was used to determine naming (I guess it is if there is no explicit name given) but now I see if I give a function a custom name, the custom name is also used to determine the name of the associated log group.